# android facebook:preset_size doesn't exist in xml?

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-studio

I'm trying to set the profilepictureview in my app:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="fr.djey.testf.MainFragment"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to set the small size for the picture. I've found on internet that I have to put **facebook:preset_size=small** but it seems to don't exist anymore.

Can you tell me if there is another way to do this in xml (and not in java)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been replaced with:

**facebook:com_facebook_preset_size**="small"

in parent layout add:

**xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

It is described in upgrade guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x
 --> Upgrading the Android SDK from 4.0.1 to 4.1.0

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. I just inform you that android studio doesn't suggest it when we begin to type the line (that's why I didn't find).